# json-ld: referencing to details of a schema:Person

Tags: semantic-web, json-ld

Is it possible to reference a property on a blank node? In the following example, what would be the way to express that `Secret Agent 2` knows that the email `james@007.uk` belongs to `Secret Agent 1` ? The following is based on  [this example for blank nodes](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#identifying-blank-nodes)

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@id": "_:n1",
  "name": "Secret Agent 1",
  "email": "james@007.uk",         //the property I want to add
  "knows": {
    "name": "Secret Agent 2",
    "knows": {
      "@id": "_:n1"
    },
    "knowsAbout": {                //Agent 2 knows that an email
      "@id": "_:n1#email"          //is the contact for Secret Agent 1
    }                              //and that the email is "james@007.uk"
  }
}
```

When trying that [in the json-ld playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3An1%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Secret%20Agent%201%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22james%40007.uk%22%2C%22knows%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22Secret%20Agent%202%22%2C%22knows%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3An1%22%7D%2C%22knowsAbout%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3An1%23email%22%7D%7D%7D), the bit with `"@id": "_:n1#email"` is interpreted as a new node `_:b2` which doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this in JSON-LD, or really in RDF in general. This document describes two entities each with a set of properties and assets that each knows the other. The relationship is between entities, and not about specific properties of those entities.

You could make the email address, itself, an entity, and then claim some relationship to it. For example, schema.org has a [PropertyValueSpecification](https://schema.org/PropertyValueSpecification), which is can have an `@id`, and therefore could be referenced, but that is not how I would choose to model it.

[JSON-LD-star](https://json-ld.github.io/json-ld-star/) is a proposed specification for describing the properties of relationships themselves (a variation on [RDF-star](https://w3c.github.io/rdf-star/cg-spec/2021-02-18.html)), so you could create the relationship `_:n1 :email "james@007.uk"` as an entity, but this doesn't really get to the indirection you describe. Still, it could look something like the following:

```
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@id": "_:n1",
  "email": "james@007.uk",
  "knows": {
    "name": "Secret Agent 2",
    "knows": {
      "@id": "_:n1"
    },
    "knowsAbout": {
      "@id": {
        "@id": "_:n1",
        "email": "james@007.uk"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But note that these are just proposed standards.

If you were to use the `PropertyValueSpecification` indirection (or some similar piece of modeling), you could say that you know about the email and it's relationship to `_:n1` without divulging the actual email, itself, but this is definitely non-typically data modeling.

Comment: great answer, thanks! I'm experimenting with mapping parts of json-ld to imperative code, so the `PropertyValueSpecification` is very useful. From the modeling perspective the information  on `PropertyValueSpecification` is really just useful when trying to modify the property, so I'm still a bit puzzled why something akin to getters like `secretAgentOne.knows["SecretAgentTwo"].knowsAbout` is so hard to model

Comment: There are RDF-adjacent ways of saying this. A blank node, such as `_:n1` is actual an _existential quantifier_ (there exists ...), So, the JSON-LD could be read is "There exists something with the email 'james@007.uk" that knows something with the name 'Secret Agent 2' ... A blank node could be substituted for the 'james@007.uk' to logically say that they know there is an email address. SPARQL and Notation-3 take advantage of this for querying and reasoning.